# AWS EBS volume attachement using snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I am trying with AWS EBS volume. I created an EC2 Server using the AMI rancheros-v0.7.1-hvm-1. Then I attached volume and mounted to /var/lib/docker folder. Then I run few docker images on that server and I am able to access those applications also.

Later I created a snapshot of the volume. and launched another server using the same AMI and attached an EBS volume from the snapshot I created earlier and mounted to /var/lib/docker folder.

After that I ssh to the second server and did docker PS. But no docker Images are running there.

When I do `df -kh` command on first server the output was:

```
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvdb                29.4G      1.2G     26.7G   4% /var/lib/docker
/dev/xvdb                29.4G      1.2G     26.7G   4% /var/lib/docker/overlay
overlay                  29.4G      1.2G     26.7G   4% /var/lib/docker/overlay
.........
```

And followed by the docker images running.

But when I did the same command on the second server I got the output like this:

```
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on

/dev/xvdb                29.4G     44.1M     27.8G   0% /var/lib/docker
/dev/xvdb                29.4G     44.1M     27.8G   0% /var/lib/docker/overlay
```

No docker images running also.

In both servers the use% are different.

Can any one tell me how can I check both are similar, and the snapshot contains all the data in the EBS volume? If the snapshot contains the similar data in the volume, then the second server should contain the docker images. But in my case its not happening.

This is the user data I gave while creating the EC2 server.

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb

mkdir -p /var/lib/docker
echo "/dev/xvdb /var/lib/docker ext4 defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
mount /dev/xvdb /var/lib/docker -t ext4

chown -R 1000 /var/lib/docker
```

Can anyone tell me a solution for this?

Comment: can anyone please help me on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked now.
the server which I created from snapshot I should not create the file system. I have to remove this command
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb
from the user data. just create the folder and mount it. then it worked.